# Implementing dry-run in ruby

Tags: scripting, ruby

anybody know how to implement dry-run option in Ruby?

I need something like this, but only for ruby.
https://serverfault.com/questions/147628/implementing-dry-run-in-bash-scripts

I've tried this, but part after `else` doesn't work:

```
DRY_RUN = true

def perform(*args)
  command = args
  if DRY_RUN
    command.each{|x| puts x}
  else
   command.each {|x| x}
  end
end

perform("puts 'Hello'")
```

Thanks for any idea in advance.

P.S I don't want use something like `system("ruby -e \"puts 'Hello'\"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the else sentence, where you have:

```
command.each { |x| x }
```

Replace that with either `system(x)` if you are running a system command, or `eval(x)` if you are trying to run ruby code, like:

```
DRY_RUN = true

def perform(*args)
  command = args
  if DRY_RUN
    command.each{ |x| puts x }
  else
   command.each { |x| system(x) }
  end
end
```

or

```
DRY_RUN = true

def perform(*args)
  command = args
  if DRY_RUN
    command.each{ |x| puts x }
  else
   command.each { |x| eval(x) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes! It works pretty good! Thank you a lot, @rorra. 
Problem resolved.